# How to make the front-end RTL without changing the admin panel language?

Tags: wp-admin, admin, front-end, language

I'm working on a website that needs to be RTL, after reading some articles online I understood that in order for the website to be RTL I need to change the site language to a RTL language.

Through this path:
**Settings >> General >> Site Language**

Did that and it changed the website to RTL but it changed all the website's content (front-end and admin panel) to the RTL language.

Can I change only the front-end part to RTL without changing my admin panel's language?

Thanks.

Comment: tu use differents languages  in frontend and backend, you can use a plugin like Polylang : https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/

Comment: check this, here exactly answered
https://wptavern.com/wordpress-4-7-to-introduce-user-specific-language-setting-for-the-admin

Comment: I had this exact problem and almost went for a multilingual plugin just to solve it. What eventually solved it for me is to set the global site language to be Arabic (settings -> general), and then going to my user (in users) and setting my preferred language to English.

Answer (score 0):

Set your WordPress to a RTL language, then use the following code in `functions.php` or as the plugin:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'locale', 'my_set_admin_locale' );

function my_set_admin_locale( $locale ) {

    // check if you are in the Admin area
    if( is_admin() ) {
        // set LTR locale
        $locale = 'en_US';
    }

    return( $locale );
}
```

Or otherwise, set WordPress to LTR and set front-end to RTL:

```
    if( ! is_admin() ) { // not admin area
        // set RTL locale
        $locale = 'ar';
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but it wasn't working for me. What made it work for me is to make the global site language to be Arabic (in settings->general), then going to the specific admin user (in users) and set the preferred language of the user (which is me) to English.

Comment: @Ghadir thanks, you suggestion helped

Answer (score 0):

Like so :

```php
add_filter('locale', function ($locale) {

    global $wp_locale;

    if (isset($_COOKIE['farsi'])) {
        $wp_locale->text_direction = 'rtl';
        return 'fa_IR';

    } else {
        $wp_locale->text_direction = 'ltr';
        return 'en_US';
    }

});
```